# how to read json file array objets with python flask

Tags: arrays, json, python-3.x, flask, encoding

I have a problem with read a file JSON, that file contains an array objects like this:

```
[{"some": 1, "list": [{"one":1}]},{"some": 1, "list": [{"one":1}]}]
```

my code is like below:

```
ls_plano = json.loads(open("tests/mocks/lsplano_itens_pessoais.json", encoding="utf8").read())
```

show me this error:

[image]

I try to read that file and put that file in ls_plano to read and assign to the other values like this:

```
        ls_plano = json.loads(open("tests/mocks/lsplano_itens_pessoais.json", encoding="utf8").read())
    if ls_plano is not None:
        for plano in ls_plano:
            temp_plano = {}
            temp_plano["inPlanoPersonalizado"] = plano.get("inPlanoPersonalizado")
            temp_plano["inSelecionado"] = plano.get("inSelecionado")
            if plano.get("lsChassi"):
                temp_plano["lsChassi"] = self.__map_ls_chassi(plano.get("lsChassi", []))
            if plano.get("lsTipoObjetoSegurado"):
                temp_plano["lsTipoObjetoSegurado"] = self.__map_ls_tipo_ob_segurado(
                    plano.get("lsTipoObjetoSegurado")
                )
            if plano.get("lsComissao"):
                temp_plano["lsComissao"] = self.__map_ls_comissao(plano.get("lsComissao", []))
            if plano.get("lsParcela"):
                temp_plano["lsParcela"] = self.__map_ls_items(plano.get("lsParcela", []))
            temp_plano["nmIdentificadorPlano"] = plano.get("nmIdentificadorPlano")
            temp_plano["nmPlano"] = plano.get("nmPlano")
            temp_plano["nrPlano"] = plano.get("nrPlano")
            temp_plano["vlAdicionalFracionamento"] = plano.get("vlAdicionalFracionamento")
            temp_plano["vlAssistenciaFacultativa"] = plano.get("vlAssistenciaFacultativa")
            temp_plano["vlCobranca"] = plano.get("vlCobranca")
            temp_plano["vlComercial"] = plano.get("vlComercial")
            temp_plano["vlIof"] = plano.get("vlIof")
            temp_plano["vlPremioLiquido"] = plano.get("vlPremioLiquido")
            temp_plano["vlPremioNet"] = plano.get("vlPremioNet")
            temp_plano["vlPremioTarifa"] = plano.get("vlPremioTarifa")
            temp_plano["vlPremioTotal"] = plano.get("vlPremioTotal")
            temp_plano["vlTotalComissao"] = plano.get("vlTotalComissao")
            temp_plano["vlTotalDesconto"] = plano.get("vlTotalDesconto")
            resp.append(temp_plano)
    return resp
```

please help me, thanks for your attention.

Comment: Have you tried disabling that plugin that raises those exceptions? Because wtf are those exceptions, how does it interpret `open` as a key or an attribute, what?

Comment: hello Matiiss, is not plugin I was debugin, and always that read that file show me that error, is project flask normal I am using import json.

Comment: Alright, well, those errors don't seem directly related to that line, that line looks fine to me, so it either is the debugger as you say, that's failing for some reason or it's something else, either way it can't have anything to do with the json file, flask is alright, like, the issue is with that plugin (I guess debugger could be considered a plugin too)

Comment: I get it, well my problem is the json.loads(open) not open the json file, my json file contains an array objects, but thanks for your comments.

Comment: Well, do you get an error that it can't open the file or what? What you have shown seems like the debugger failing not the actual code.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use **with** when opening files, it's a better approach, [see here more info](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/file-operation).

This code is working:

```
import sys

# Reading the json file
try:
    with open("myjsonfile_list_of_dicts.json", "r") as read_content:
        ls_plano: dict = json.load(read_content)
except (FileNotFoundError, PermissionError, OSError, ValueError) as e:
    print(f"Error opening the file: {e}")
    sys.exit()

# Parsing
try:
    resp = []
    if ls_plano is not None:
        for plano in ls_plano:
            temp_plano = {"inPlanoPersonalizado": plano.get("inPlanoPersonalizado"),
                          "inSelecionado": plano.get("inSelecionado")}
            if plano.get("lsChassi"):
                temp_plano["lsChassi"] = self.__map_ls_chassi(plano.get("lsChassi", []))
            if plano.get("lsTipoObjetoSegurado"):
                temp_plano["lsTipoObjetoSegurado"] = self.__map_ls_tipo_ob_segurado(
                    plano.get("lsTipoObjetoSegurado")
                )
            if plano.get("lsComissao"):
                temp_plano["lsComissao"] = self.__map_ls_comissao(plano.get("lsComissao", []))
            if plano.get("lsParcela"):
                temp_plano["lsParcela"] = self.__map_ls_items(plano.get("lsParcela", []))
            temp_plano["nmIdentificadorPlano"] = plano.get("nmIdentificadorPlano")
            temp_plano["nmPlano"] = plano.get("nmPlano")
            temp_plano["nrPlano"] = plano.get("nrPlano")
            temp_plano["vlAdicionalFracionamento"] = plano.get("vlAdicionalFracionamento")
            temp_plano["vlAssistenciaFacultativa"] = plano.get("vlAssistenciaFacultativa")
            temp_plano["vlCobranca"] = plano.get("vlCobranca")
            temp_plano["vlComercial"] = plano.get("vlComercial")
            temp_plano["vlIof"] = plano.get("vlIof")
            temp_plano["vlPremioLiquido"] = plano.get("vlPremioLiquido")
            temp_plano["vlPremioNet"] = plano.get("vlPremioNet")
            temp_plano["vlPremioTarifa"] = plano.get("vlPremioTarifa")
            temp_plano["vlPremioTotal"] = plano.get("vlPremioTotal")
            temp_plano["vlTotalComissao"] = plano.get("vlTotalComissao")
            temp_plano["vlTotalDesconto"] = plano.get("vlTotalDesconto")
            resp.append(temp_plano)
    return resp

except (KeyError, TypeError) as e:
    print(f"Error parsing the json file: {e}")
```

## Recommendations:

- Comment the code
- Use [try-except](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp)
- [Open files with 'with'](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/file-operation)